# Sort files by highest number in filename

Tags: shell-script, files

I've got a bunch of files all named like this:

```
name_file-1.txt
name_file-2.txt
name_file-3.txt
some_other_file-1.txt
some_other_file-2.txt
```

There are thousands of different filenames, some with just one `-1.txt` at the end, some with `-1.txt`, `-2.txt` ... `-60.txt`

I need to copy the highest numbers of each file, so `name_file-3.txt`, `some_other_file-2.txt`. How do I do that on a Linux command line?

Comment: In the source dir `cp -t /path_to_destination $(ls -v *[0-9].txt | sed 'N;/\([^\n]*-\)[0-9]\+\.txt\n\1/!P;D')`

Comment: @Costas: Why don't you make this an answer?

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -A greatest
for f (*-*(n)) greatest[${f%-*}]=$f
cp -- $greatest /destination
```

- `*-*(n)`: non-hidden files whose name contains a `-` (`*-*`), sorted numerically (`(n)` glob qualifier).
- `${f%-*}`: part of the filename up to the right-most `-` (or to the end if there's no `-`).
- `$greatest`: expands to the non-empty *values* of the associative arrays. So here, for files that share the same root, only the file with the greatest number will be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

```
files=(*)
mapfile -t prefixes < <(printf "%s\n" "${files[@]%-*}" | sort -u)
for p in "${prefixes[@]}"; do ls -v "$p"* | tail -1; done
```

```
name_file-3.txt
some_other_file-2.txt
```

And then to copy those to some other directory:

```
for ...; done | xargs cp -t /destination/directory
```

Comment: Cool! Never seen `mapfile` before!

Comment: Great! But the copy part does not seem to work...?

Comment: When copy I get this: "xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option" and also sometimes "cp: warning: source file 'fgfggfffg-2.txt' specified more than once

Comment: Where are those quotes coming from? Do you have a filename with a quote in it?

Answer (score 1):

If pwd is the source dir

```
cp -t /path_to_destination $(
      ls -v *[0-9].txt |
      sed '$b;N;/^\(.*\)[0-9]\+\.txt\n\1[0-9]\+\.txt/!P;D')
```

NOTE: If there are any spaces in file names it should be prepared before by escaping to proper operation. + see other restrictions in [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)' comments

Comment: Might break if OP has files such as `file-2.txt` and `file-other-1.txt`

Comment: @Otheus You are right. Have edited.

Comment: @Otheus The `!` negates match == `if not`

Comment: Ahh, so that's what sed's `D` is good for.

Comment: Remember the problem with unquoted expansions is not only above spaces, it's about any $IFS character and glob wildcards.

Comment: You'll also have problems with filenames starting with `-` here. Or if some of those files are of type directory (or symlink to directory). `ls -vd -- ...`

Comment: Note that `-t`, `-v`, `\+` are GNU-specific extensions.

Comment: It won't work if there's a `ab-1.txt` and `b-2.txt`, you'll want to anchor your pattern (`/^\(...txt$/`)

Comment: For non-GNU `sed`s, or if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment, you'll need to replace `N` with `$!N`.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in the current working directory and their names conform to the samples (a single dash which precedes a number), the following POSIX-compliant pipeline should work:

```
ls | sort -t- -k1,1 -k2,2rn | awk -F- 'k!=$1 {print; k=$1}' | pax -rw /path/to/dir
```

The awk component can be replaced by a sort -u, if the sort's -u option is stable (so that the first line of a set is always chosen to represent that set). POSIX does not require this stability, but, according to their manuals, the {Free,Net,Open}BSD and GNU implementations provide it. If you enjoy tempting fate:

```
ls | sort -t- -k1,1 -k2,2rn | sort -mut- -k1,1 | pax -rw /path/to/dir
```

In either case, the target directory must not be in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the file into tab-delimited parts for more reliable, customizable filename parsing, then use awk to find the highest rank of each and report. Try each part of the pipeline first before proceeding to next!

```
find DIR -type f <other find criteron> -print | 
perl -lne 'print join("\t",(/^(.*?-)(\d+)(\.\w+)$/))' |
awk -F\\t '$2 > f[$1] { f[$1]=$2;e[$1]=$3; } END { for (k in f) { print k f[k] e[k] }}' |
xargs cp -t <desination_directory>
```

The awk script puts each filename in an associate array entry, always keeping the highest rank found. The extension is stored in its own array. After all input is processed, all array entries are output, one per line. The `xargs cp -t` line copies all the files to the directory you specify.

There's another method which **won't work** very well if the numbers are greater than 9 and are not 0-padded. That method sorts the files lexicographically, then when parsing the list, the first part changes, the most recently seen filename is used. When the filenames are like this, it won't work:

```
file-9.txt
file-10.txt
```

because file-10.txt will appear before file-9. The awk script above does a numerical comparison.

CAVEAT: Filenames with tabs and newlines will cause this to choke.

CAVEAT 2: If multiple extensions per filename prefix are possible, we will have to make some tweaks to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a command-line answer, per-se, but on the assumption that you have `bash` version >= 4 available, here's a bash script that gathers all of the *.txt files, determines their numbered suffix, then saves the highest-numbered suffix seen into an associative array (indexed by the base part of the filename before the numbered suffix). It the prints back out a sample `cp` commands for each filename with the highest suffix seen.

Adjust the destination "somedir" as needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A highest
for f in *.txt
do
  base=${f%%.txt}
  prefix=${base%-*}
  postfix=${base/$prefix-/}
  if [[ ${highest[$prefix]} -lt $postfix ]]
  then
    highest[$prefix]=$postfix
  fi
done

for prefix in "${!highest[@]}"
do
  escaped=${prefix//\"/\\\"}
  printf "cp -- \"%s\" somedir/\n" "$escaped-${highest[$prefix]}.txt"
done
```

In a directory of these files:

```
-dash-1.txt
-dash-2.txt
double"quote-3.txt
file'here-1.txt
filetwo'here'-2.txt
name_file-1.txt
name_file-2.txt
name_file-3.txt
somefile-5.txt
somefile-60.txt
some_other_file-1.txt
some_other_file-2.txt
space file-1.txt
space file-2.txt
```

The output is (manually sorted, for easier reading):

```
cp -- "-dash-2.txt" somedir/
cp -- "double\"quote-3.txt" somedir/
cp -- "file'here-1.txt" somedir/
cp -- "filetwo'here'-2.txt" somedir/
cp -- "name_file-3.txt" somedir/
cp -- "somefile-60.txt" somedir/
cp -- "some_other_file-2.txt" somedir/
cp -- "space file-2.txt" somedir/
```